# How to make google index only images of a page?

Tags: iframe, seo, google-image-search, noindex

I have a page that contains a lot of images, but it's a page designed to be in an iframe inside an other page. I dont want this page to be indexed to prevent visitors to be stuck in this iframe, but I want to make index all the pictures inside the iframe.

The iframe is a picture slider that opens over the page, there is previous/next buttons and the picture. I find bad to put in the meta robots "NOINDEX, FOLLOW" and to make a link on the pictures to the originial picture... because the picture is already fullscreen. My other option is to put a link back to the parent page, but because the iframe is opened over the page, it would be bad to have a page opened over the same page. what do I do ?

If I do not index this page, only my thumbnails will show up in google image. do you hate thumbnails in google images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally indexed the page and put a link back to the source page using a javascript condition : if the page is not opened in an iframe, show the link to go back to the previous source page.